# Should I be able to re-use csrf tokens within the same session when using npm csurf?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

When using [csurf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) I've noticed that if I present a ***previously generated and used*** csrf token, it is still accepted as a valid token (within the same session).

Should this be the case or am I using it wrong? I would have expected a used csrf token to become invalidated (so it can only be used once per session id).

My code looks something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var csurf = require('csurf');
app.use(csurf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet): "Synchronizer (CSRF) Tokens (are) Unique per user session" which I take to mean that *they are tied to the session*. This means that it is possible to re-use a token from the same session. Hence the answer to the question is 'yes'.

It seems then that [npm csurf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) is using a standard best practice by allowing the re-use of csrf tokens within the same session (even after they have been consumed once).

Relevant part from OWASP:

**Synchronizer (CSRF) Tokens**

> Any state changing operation requires a secure random token (e.g.,
>   CSRF token) to prevent CSRF attacks

**Characteristics of a CSRF Token**

- Unique per user session
- Large random value
- Generated by a cryptographically secure random number generator

> The CSRF token is added as a hidden field for forms or within the URL
>   if the state changing operation occurs via a GET The server rejects
>   the requested action if the CSRF token fails validation